# Specifying a signatory from another contract

Tags: smartcontracts, daml

In Daml, I have setup an `Agent` contract. This is its down `Agent.daml` file. I then have a proposal contract (`Proposal.daml`), in which I imported the `Agent` module. I wanted to specify `agentname` is the signatory for the proposal contract, but compiler tells me that no such party exists.

There are no parties in my `Proposal` contract which is why I chose a party from another contract. I'm not sure how to solve this?

This is the agent contract

```
module Agent where


-- MAIN_TEMPLATE_BEGIN
template Agent with
  agentname: Party
  guarantors: [Party]
where

  signatory agentname
  observer guarantors
```

And this is the `Proposal` contract

```
module Proposal where

import Agent

-- MAIN_TEMPLATE_BEGIN
template Proposal with

  projectdescription: Text
  unitsrequired: Int
  marketingcost: Int
  distributioncost: Int
  additionalcost: Int

where
  signatory agentname
  observer guarantors

-- MAIN_TEMPLATE_END

     key agentname: Party   
     maintainer key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signatories of a contract need to be computable from the contract arguments. You can't reference another contract by `ContractId` and get them from there. The reason is that that other contract might be archived, in which case you suddenly have a contract for which the signatories can't be read.

So your `Proposal` must contain the agent that is making the proposal:

```
template Proposal with
  agent : Party
  projectdescription: Text
  unitsrequired: Int
  marketingcost: Int
  distributioncost: Int
  additionalcost: Int
where
  signatory agent
  ...
```

As a little aside: `Party` is not in general a human-readable string so best not to use them as "names". If you want a human-readable name, add a `name : Text` field to `Agent`.

Now you may wonder: How do I enforce the constraint that for every `Proposal` there exists an `Agent`? There's a [long and informative thread](https://discuss.daml.com/t/indicate-list-of-or-signatories/786) on that topic on the Daml forums.